# how to get a block of code to run only once in a loop in fortran in a case where the condition repeats

Tags: fortran

I am running a program in fortran 95. The loop contains a set of conditional actions that reverses under set limits. Please can someone advise me on how to get a block of code to run only once in a loop, such that it does repeat when the condition is met, but runs the rest of the code until the number of iterations is complete?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you provide some code of what you have tried? Have you tried a 'do while (condition)' loop? What do you mean by 'runs rest of code until iterations is complete?'? Either the program is running inside the do loop or it continues to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question several times, I think I know what you want. If you want a piece of code to always run at least once inside a do loop but possibly repeat, you can try something like this. Start with a logical variable to ensure one execution:

```
once = .true.
do i = 1, whatever
   some code
   if (once .or. (another condition)) then
      once = .false.
      code will always run once but possibly repeat
   end if
   can have more code
enddo
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your advise. I tried to apply this advise but the code simply could not build. It does not recognise the 'once=.true. ' . I have just posted a more direct description in my next question. You may please have a look and advise accordingly.

Comment: As described in your next post in comments, you will get better responses if you post a complete program. As for above, did you declare the variable 'once' as logical?

Comment: Thanks Dan., The program is relatively long. I will reduce it to an extent that it can still achieve what I want and then post it.